# Google sheets JSON API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from google sheets as JSON format by send request to with ID so I get back all data of that ID. I'm using this script for that task but I have two issues:

1. Script gives error if data was not found.
2. I I have two records of the same ID, I get only the first record.

## my code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17IIEmFXjmKZpqRlj8fs4XV7t859TLY_D24sqvrhc9Pc");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data")
var rng = ss.getDataRange()
var data = rng.getValues()
var headings = data[0]

/* Take a product ID as input and return the
 *  row corresponding to that product ID.*/

function productQuery(prodId){
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    if (prodId === data[i][0]){
      return data[0]
    }
  }
}

/* Take a spreadsheet (product) row and turn it into an object
 with spreadsheet headings as object keys. */

function formatProduct(rowData){
  var product = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++){
    product[headings[i].toString()] = rowData[i]
  }
  return product
}

function doGet(request) {
  // Check for a valid request URI
  if (request.parameter.action !== undefined){
    if (request.parameter.prodid !== undefined){
      prodIds = request.parameters.prodid
      
      // The object to be returned as JSON
      response = {
        products : []
      }
      
      // Fill the products array with requested products
      for (var i = 0; i < prodIds.length; i++){   
        sheetData = productQuery(prodIds[i])
        product = formatProduct(sheetData)
        response.products.push(product)
      }
      
      if (response.products.length > 0){
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
      } else {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Product ID(s) not found.');
      }      
    } else {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Use at least one valid "prodid" parameter.');
    } 
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Use a valid "action" parameter.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail where do you make use of your functions?

Comment: Here's the [link] (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw68Lig9kmPoWlc-azP77kt3UID57n-gC5XU7tb6eozUmSUAVdO/exec?action=get&prodid=g123)

Comment: You mean you have two *products* with the same ID? Your `productQuery()` function only returns one product, so just update that function. Also, consider whether it makes sense to have non-unique IDs.

Comment: Diego could make that modification plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

In order to solve you issue, you have to change your functions **productQuery**, **formatProduct** and **doGet**.

As per the [Google Apps Script - Web Apps deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) example, you retrieve a list in the **request.parameters** value. For that reason if you want to get many objects from your App, you can make these changes to your functions:

### Code

```
function productQuery(prodId){
 let dataList = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
   if (prodId === data[i][0]){
     dataList.push(data[i]); // This should return data[i] instead of the first row which is the header
   }
 }
  return dataList; // Return a list of products instead
}
```

```
function formatProduct(rowData){
 var product = {}
 for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++){
   product[headings[i].toString()] = rowData[i]
 }
 return product
}
```

```
function doGet(request) {
 // Check for a valid request URI
 if (request.parameter.action !== undefined){ // This parameter is not used in the code
   if (request.parameter.prodid !== undefined){
     let prodIds = request.parameters.prodid
    
     // The object to be returned as JSON
     let response = {
       products : []
     }
    
     // Fill the products array with requested products
     for (var i = 0; i < prodIds.length; i++){  
     /** CHANGES - START*/
       productQuery(prodIds[i]).forEach(sheetData => { // Iterate trough the items list
         let product = formatProduct(sheetData)
         response.products.push(product)
       })
     /** CHANGES - END*/
     }
    
     if (response.products.length > 0){
       return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
     } else {
       return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Product ID(s) not found.');
     }     
   } else {
     return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Use at least one valid "prodid" parameter.');
   }
 } else {
   return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Use a valid "action" parameter.');
 }
}
```

### Query

***Assuming we have a duplicate ID equal to “g1”.***

#### Example 1

Retrieve single item by ID:

https://script.google.com/.../exec?action=1&prodid=g123

Reponse:

{"products":[{"ID":"g123","Name":"First Rec","Price":20,"Stock":35}]}

#### Example 2

Retrieve items with duplicate ID:

https://script.google.com/.../exec?action=1&prodid=g1

Response:

{"products":[{"ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21},{"ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21}]}

#### Example 3

Retrieve different items:

https://script.google.com/.../exec?action=1&prodid=g1&prodid=g2

Response:

{"products":[{"ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21},{"ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21},{"ID":"g2","Name":"name","Price":44,"Stock":12}]}

Comment: in case there are duplicated ID, is it possible to add preceded serial number before each record for example:   {"products":[{"Serial":"1-","ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21},{"Serial":"2-","ID":"g1","Name":"name","Price":22,"Stock":21}]}